# How to debug syslog-ng not logging UDP logs

Tags: logging, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am trying to get a client to log to a syslog-ng server. However, as far as I can tell, syslog-ng is not registering that it has received the message and it has not logged to the file.

NOTE : All commands were run as root

This is my syslog-ng.conf

```
options {
        flush_lines (0);
        time_reopen (10);
        log_fifo_size (1000);
        long_hostnames (off);
        use_dns (no);
        use_fqdn (no);
        create_dirs (no);
        keep_hostname (yes);
};

source s_net {
        udp(port(514));
};

destination d_net {
        file("/var/log/test.log");
};
```

These are the permissions of the messages and test.log file (I know that messages is being written to by syslog-ng).

```
ls -lah test.log messages
-rw-------. 1 root root 73K Sep  4 10:19 messages
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   0 Sep  4 10:28 test.log
```

In order to test connectivity, I run the following test.
On the server with syslog-ng, I run the following commands :

```
service syslog-ng stop 
syslog-ng -dv (debug verbose mode)
nc -ul 514 (listen to udp packets on port 514)
```

On the client I run the following commands

```
nc -u IP_OF_SERVER 514
Hello World (Hit Enter)
```

On the server I see that I have received the udp message :

```
[root@rhel6-64 syslog-ng]# nc -ul 514
Hello World
```

But I don't see anything on the syslog-ng output :

```
[root@rhel6-64 syslog-ng]# syslog-ng -dv
Trying to open module; module='syslogformat', filename='/lib64/syslog-ng/libsyslogformat.so'
Trying to open module; module='basicfuncs', filename='/lib64/syslog-ng/libbasicfuncs.so'
Trying to open module; module='afsocket', filename='/lib64/syslog-ng/libafsocket.so'
Trying to open module; module='affile', filename='/lib64/syslog-ng/libaffile.so'
Trying to open module; module='afprog', filename='/lib64/syslog-ng/libafprog.so'
Trying to open module; module='afuser', filename='/lib64/syslog-ng/libafuser.so'
Trying to open module; module='dbparser', filename='/lib64/syslog-ng/libdbparser.so'
Trying to open module; module='csvparser', filename='/lib64/syslog-ng/libcsvparser.so'
Plugin module not found in 'module-path'; module-path='/lib64/syslog-ng', module='afsql'
Running application hooks; hook='1'
Running application hooks; hook='3'
syslog-ng starting up; version='3.2.5'
```

Note that "syslog-ng starting up; version='3.2.5'" is the last thing I see.

At this stage, I am not sure what the problem is and I would like someone to explain my problem is, or how to debug this problem further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't read the man pages well enough. When I defined a source and a destination, I did not define a link between them (I had assumed that since they both had _net after the s and d that they would automatically link to each other). Instead I needed the following line to be added to syslog-ng.conf

```
log { source(s_net); destination(d_net); }
```

To summarize, my problem was that I didn't connect the two endpoints and the solution is to specify the connection between the endpoints by using the log block.